# Problems with Data Quality Services Cleansing Activity

Tags: sql-server, data-cleaning, data-quality-services

I am working my way through MOC 20767c; the last section of modules in preparation for the MCSE Data Management and Analysis certification.
I'm doing all the labs and demonstrations; and, I don't understand the reason DQS's behavior.  For any of you who may have the text book, I'm in the demo on page 10-12.

I'll walk through the steps here:

1. Ensure you have completed the previous demonstration in this module.  **Completed w/o Error**
2. In SQL Server Data Quality Services, in the **Data Quality Projects** section, click **New Data Quality Project**.  **Completed w/o Error**
3. In the **Name** box, type **Cleansing Demo**.  **Completed w/o Error**
4. In the **Use Knowledge Base** list, ensure **Demo KB** is selected. **Completed w/o Error**
5. In the **Select Activity** section, ensure **Cleansing** is selected, and then click **Next**. **Completed w/o Error**
6. On the **Map** page, in the **Data Source** list, ensure **SQL Server** is selected. **Completed w/o Error**
7. In the **Database** list, click **DemoDQS**.  **Error; I do not have a **DemoDQS** database** The only database that appears is one called **DQS_STAGING_DATA**.

I have tried this and the demo before it every which way from Sunday.  I have even gone so far as to uninstall SQL Server and start from scratch using my crash & burn system.

I have experimented; manually creating a DemoDQS database using SQL Server Management Studio to see what would happen.  The database DemoDQS then appears as an option in #7 above; but, the database is empty: no tables, no columns. **Not really a surprise**.

I have Googled DemoDQS and have come up dry.  I have searched Microsoft Docs and have come up dry.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question can be closed under an official close reason of "Typo/Unreproducible".

Answer (score 0):

Blame it on pilot error. There was a setup.cmd file that I missed that would have created the DemoDQS DB and tables had I seen it.